# Adding new card to stripe overwrites the old one

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I already have a customer with one card and I'm trying to add another card to them. This is my request:

```
function stripe_post (route, data) {  
  return fetch(STRIPE_API + route, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${STRIPE_ACCESS_KEY}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
      body: serialize(data)   }) }

stripe_post(`customers/${stripeId}`, {
        source: {
          object: 'card',
          exp_month: card.expiry.slice(0, 2),
          exp_year: card.expiry.slice(-2),
          number: card.number,
          name: card.name,
          cvc: card.cvc
        }
      })
```

Which returns the correct new card object but when I try to fetch the customer object afterwards the new card has overwritten the old one inside that object.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected: you're [updating a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer) with a new card. If you want to add a new card instead, you need to use this API request: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card.

Also, I'm not sure where you're executing this code from, but:

- if this is client-side code, you're sharing your secret key with your frontend code which reveals it publicly. This API request needs to be fired from backend code.
- if this is server-side code, your server has access to the raw card information, which makes ineligible for PCI SAQ A. You should be tokenizing the card information client-side using [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) or [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout), then using the card token in the server-side request
- if you want to integrate Stripe with Node.js, you should use the official [stripe-node](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#stripe-nodejs-bindings-) library rather than crafting the API requests yourself.